# Convert Mon Sep 17 05:52:14 EDT 2018 type date format to simple Date and Time android

Tags: android

I am currently working on a chat application by using Firestore. When I try to get Timestamp from firestore Document with
Date `date=documentSnapshot.getDate(fieldvalue1,DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior.ESTIMATE);`
then it returns to date in "Mon Sep 17 05:52:14 EDT 2018" this format.I am not able to convert that date into Simple date format. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy` pattern for retrieve date from string. Like,

```
 SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
 try {
      Date date2 = format.parse(dateStr);         
     } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

**EDIT**

You can convert into Indian time Like,

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
    try {
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT-04:00"));    //for EDT

        Date date2 = format.parse(dateStr);

        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30");   //for Indian Time
        format.setTimeZone(tz);
        String result = format.format(date2);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you.Let me try and reply u back.

Comment: I already got it in Date format.How to convert it in to Simple date and time india.

Comment: Thank you.This pattern is working fine Can you tell me how to convert that time into  Indian time.

Comment: I had nailed it.Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Check Edited Answer.